# Include Google Font in Angular 2 + Meteor Application

Tags: javascript, meteor, fonts, angular, angular2-meteor

Newb to Angular 2 .

How to include Google font in my app.
App Structure is

client
      |--app.ts
      |--main.ts
      |--index.html

**IndexFile.html**

```
<head></head>
<body style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <app-start>Loading...</app-start>
    </div>
</body>
```

Included link in head tag

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

but no effect has occurred, also created a JS file in client folder (font.js) and inserted code

```
  Meteor.startup(function() {

  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Montserrat::latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })();

 })
```

But no effect.

Right way to include this font in my Angular 2 + Meteor Application

Comment: have you include the font family into the css?

Comment: I have included inline CSS inside body tag

Comment: Weird, the link in head should work. Because I am using this way, it is working properly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found solution using @import 
Inserted this code in common_style.css file which I placed in public folder

client
     |--app.ts
     |--main.ts
     |--index.html
public
     |--styles
          |--common_style.css

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
```

And then on app.ts - main loader typescript file I have included the style

```
@Component({
  selector:'app-start',
  template:`
        <div style=" font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">
        <navbar></navbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <footer></footer>
        </div>
  `,
  directives : [ NavbarComponent,FooterComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
  providers  : [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ]
})
```

and got style on all the pages